# How to regex just the second half of firsthalf.secondhalf():

Tags: regex

Having trouble getting the regex to work for this. I want to basically just recognize the second half of something like this: `firsthalf.secondhalf():` as a function. So in the example above just the `.secondhalf()`: would be recognized as unique and different color than the firsthalf.

I've tried, but to no avail:

```
<regex>(\w*()\b)</regex>
```

Comment: You need to escape the () so \ ( \ ) try http://regexr.com/ it's great for building and testing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
(\w*\(\):)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/HbcVb8mxKJKKyr7H)

Answer (score 0):

```
\w*\(\)\:$
```

`\w*` match any word character [a-zA-Z0-9_]

Quantifier: `*` Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]

`\(` matches the character ( literally

`\)` matches the character ) literally

`\:` matches the character : literally

`$` assert position at end of the string

Comment: This didn't work for me. When i would write firsthalf.secondhalf(): and then space after the :, it would go back to default grey.

Comment: oh, i thought the (): was the end of the string. if you take out `$` it'll work